# Bound of Angle Between Minimal Vectors of a Lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, number-theory

I am considering a sublattice $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{Z}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of dimension/rank 2. From $\Lambda$ I am pulling out a vector $\mathbf{v}_1 $ of minimal length, and a vector $\mathbf{v}_2$ of minimal length subject to the condition that $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ are linearly independent. A paper by Heath-Brown in 1984 ("Diophantine Approximation with Square-Free Numbers") states that the angle $\theta$ between these two vectors satisfies $\pi/3 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi/3$. I've been struggling to see why this is the case.

Currently what I've tried is rotating $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that $\Lambda$ has a basis vector (not necessarily distinct from the $\mathbf{v}_i$!) that lies on the $x$-axis and then using some calculus, but I can't seem to achieve the bound on $\theta$ above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See the picture at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane

Comment: @AnginaSeng I have learned about these fundamental domains in undergrad before! I'm curious as to how they're connected to my current question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are in $\Bbb R^2$. We can take coordinates so that $v_1=(a,0)$
and $v_2=(b,c)$ where $a$ and $c$ are positive. Now, we if
we consider $v_2-kv_1=(b-ka,c)$ with $k\in\Bbb Z$ we can replace $b$ by $b'=b-ka$
with $|b'|\le a/2$, without increasing the length of $v_2$. So as $v_2$ is
shortest possible, then $|b|\le a/2$. Also as $v_1$ is shortest possible, then
$a^2\le b^2+c^2$. Then
$$|v_1\cdot v_2|=|ab|\le\frac{a^2}2\le\frac{a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}2$$
and so
$$|\cos\theta|\le\frac12.$$